# Android Game development using libgdx

Tags: android

I want to ask any one who had develop game in android studio using libgdx? i need hlp.
Or tel me how can I start Game development because I am new in games.

Answer (score -1):

If you are first in gaming development, first decide which game you want to develop, then select game engine.

[Unity3D](https://unity3d.com/) is for wide range of users from beginners to expert and popular option because it can deploy the game to multiplatform.

Comment: off topic. (but the question is off-topic as well).

Comment: @njxk2 is it? He asked literally how do I start gaming development and I gave him what to consider, and which engine is better suit for beginners. Don't know how I can improve my answer.

Comment: the question is way too broad, and opinion-based. Your answer is broad too, and unity3d is a matter of opinion. The OP asks vaguely about libgdx, which you don't mention.

Comment: There are already tons of material and opinions, which much better supporting arguments, for each and every available game engine for android.

Comment: i am new im game development so i don't decide yet which type of game i want to bulit.But now i only searching for tool which is easy?I install libgdx in android studio but don't find more helpful tutorials

Comment: I need help related unity installation in win 8. becz i install unity after that hen i open  it display close program or debugger. click on close program it wil exit from unity